# lookup any domain on local machine

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, bind

I want my server to forward ALL domain requests to a single page without having to create any entries in httpd.conf or create a zone file. The page that is forwarded to will handle the request and serve up the results.

eg:
I register example.com at lets say godaddy (shudder)
add an A record pointing to my server

When a user visits example.com, the a record leads them to the server, I now want the server to show them to a certain page without having to have any record of example.com on the server.

How on earth would I go about doing this??

Umut

Comment: Doesn't apache do this by default if you don't set up any virtual hosts? What behavior are you seeing instead?

Comment: which web server do you use?

Comment: using apache
right now i just see the browsers 'unable to find www.example.com message'

Comment: Are you sure your request is really being directed to your server? If you do a `ping www.example.com` on the machine running the browser, does this `ping` show you the address of your web server? @Umut

Answer (score 1):

So I'm guessing you have no ability to modify the actual Apache configuration given that you have said:

> without having to have any record of example.com on the server

So what level of access do you have? if you have the ability to use `.htaccess` then you could potentially use mod_rewrite (assuming mod_rewrite is available on the Apache server):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.other.com/landing-page.html [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps.